# how to monitor memory in a spring + tomcat application?

Tags: spring, tomcat, memory-management

i have a spring application that i want to optimize , its using much memory, it was fine when few people used it, but numbers scaled a little and i have no idea where to start . Is there a way of knowing which class and methods take what kind of resources ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JMX will be a good start. Using Spring's JMX support, it will be very easy to configure your beans to integrate with JMX.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/jmx.html

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start with this is using a profiler. There are a lot of products out there. I personally like [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/). It's a matter of preference. Using a profiler you can easily find out the number of instantiated classes from where in the code. You might simply have a memory leak.

In general I think it's a good idea to set up your application server/servlet container to expose their internals over [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html). You'll just have to [enable the JMX agent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html) by setting JVM startup parameters. You can then connect to your server and monitor CPU and memory consumption using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). VisualVM provides a simple profiling plugin.