# Java Spring web app- utilising 140MB memory for single user performance testing

Tags: java, spring, memory-management

I have a Spring application, which in performance and load testing, gives a level of 130-140 MB memory usage and for multiple users, it goes upto 1GB. Can anyone help me with any workaround for this issue or any suggestions for the performance tuning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to monitor memory in a spring + tomcat application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405518/how-to-monitor-memory-in-a-spring-tomcat-application)

Comment: Its not to monitor.. to fine tune and reduce..

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool called [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). And otherwise hand crafting Spring AOP or AspectJ aspects.

Answer (score 0):

i have used java profilers but i am not satisfied with output for actual performance tuning and memory usage currently we have been switched to [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This not only help performance optimization in dev but also in production system. Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml